# How Array is different from Structures and Unions in C programming Language?

Tags: c, arrays, structure, unions

I am unable to understand difference between them. When the same thing is done by three of them then when we should go for Array/Structure/Union?

Comment: Array - Many elements with same data type; Structure - many elements with different data types; Union - Only one Element at a time (Biggest data type gets reserved)... As far as my pseudo-knowledge goes

Comment: Please explain why they are the same instead of stating that they are and asking why they are different. They are not the same, and they should not be used for the same purpose. It's like saying that linked lists as the same as arrays.

Comment: A Union is a struct whose data members share the same memory addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an array all the elements have the same size and type, so you can't use one for an `int` and the other one as a `double` value, and so on.

In `struct`s, every element can have a different size or type. You can use one as an `int` and the others for any data type you can use for a regular variable, you can also have arrays of structures.

The `union`s are used to use a single variable for possibly multiple data types. In a `union` the size of an instance equals the size of it's largest member, unlike in `struct`s where it equals the sum of individual member sizes.

Also, essentially the syntax is very much clearer if you use a `struct` even for members of the same type. For example, instead of having

```
float ****point3d;
```

You could have

```
struct point3d_s {
    float x, float y, float z;
};
point3d_s *point3d;
```

will declare a pointer to a 3 dimensional point, which in turn can be used as an array too.

Answer (score 2):

Well, they are three totally different objects.

Use *array* when you should have many (well, at least two...) elements of the very same type. Mainly, when the number of them might vary.
For example: Hold all the phone numbers of students in a class.

Use *struct* when you should aggregate a few variables together.
For example: Hold, per a student, their name, their phone number and their address.

Use *union* when you should always use only one variable type out of a few possible ones.
For example: Hold, per a student, *either* his phone number *or* their email address.

Comment: How can you have multiple variables of the same type in an array? Can you please clarify? Do you understand what a variable is?

Comment: @iharob: I really hate this type of question (it can be trivially answered by "learn C!") - but this answer isn't *that* bad, is it? You appear to read something in it that I cannot see.

Comment: @iharob: Well, that is exactly what an array is. Many variables of the same type. You don't "have them in an array". They *are* the array.

Comment: @iharob: I have written it in a way that I believed will be better understood by a C newbie, but I accept your change - it is, indeed, more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Array has no padding in between its elements as compared to structure. All elements of array and structure are considered for total size calculation, while union size is equal to its maximum sized element.

Array have all elements of same type, which is no prerequisite for structure and union.

Array uses index based access for accessing its elements, while structure and union uses `.element_name` for accessing its elements.